# Failed to bind to address https://[::]:443: address already in use

Tags: asp.net, docker

When running the ASP .NET Core app inside docker, the application throws an error:

Failed to bind to address https://[::]:443: address already in use

Deleting container or restarting docker doesn't help. Even though it worked before, something has happened. Any ideas?

[image]

docker conf:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.1-bullseye-slim AS base
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y libgdiplus
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdiplus.so
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends zlib1g fontconfig libfreetype6 libx11-6 libxext6 libxrender1 wget gdebi
RUN wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.stretch_amd64.deb
RUN gdebi --n wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.stretch_amd64.deb
RUN apt install libssl1.1
RUN ln -s /usr/local/lib/libwkhtmltox.so /usr/lib/libwkhtmltox.so
RUN sed -i'.bak' 's/$/ contrib/' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer fontconfig

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["GptVisualRest.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./GptVisualRest.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "GptVisualRest.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "GptVisualRest.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "GptVisualRest.dll"]
```

Comment: It's very unusual to get an error like this in a container, since there's only one process running and all ports are available. Are you by any chance using the `--net=host` option on your `docker run` command?

Comment: I agree, it's very strange. Add docker conf to post

Comment: --net=host dosen't help.

Comment: @HansKilian why you set minus to my reputation?

Comment: I didn't. Someone else did.

Answer (score 0):

I read a lot of similar posts and none of the solutions did not help.
Did re-create the self-signed certificates.
Created new project from template also did not work.
Checked occupied ports. None of the solutions worked.

**What fixed the problem:**

1. Go to Docker-Desktop => Troubleshoot
2. Press the Clean/Purge data button
3. Reboot PC.
4. Create new container
5. Work

[image]

**P. S.**
I think this is some kind of platform bug which will be fixed in future versions.

**What I used:**

- Windows Home Premium 11 version 21H2 build 22000.1696
- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.5.2
- ASP.NET Core 6.0.15
- Docker Desktop 4.17.0 (99724)
- ASP.NET and Web Tools 17.5.317.37931